# How generate XML sitemap in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xquery, sitemap

I want to generate a sitemap from within SQL Server and save it to my system drive using the following Product table:

**Sample data**

| loc | image | caption | changefreq | priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://example.com/product1 | https://example.com/asset/img1.jpg | title1 | 10 | 0.1 |
| https://example.com/product2 | https://example.com/asset/img2.jpg | title2 | 5 | 0 |

I tried using a `FOR XML PATH` query but its not giving me the correct result:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = (SELECT 
                        (SELECT 
                                '' AS "data()" 
                         FOR XML PATH ('loc'), TYPE),
                         (SELECT 
                                '' AS "data()" 
                         FOR XML PATH ('changefreq'), TYPE),
                         (SELECT 
                                '' AS "data()" 
                         FOR XML PATH ('priority'), TYPE),
                         
                                '' AS 'Name!1!ELEMENT' 
                    FROM dbo.product o 
                    FOR XML PATH ('url'), ROOT('dummyTag'), TYPE)

-- Magic happens here!       

    SELECT 1 AS Tag
          ,0 AS Parent
          ,@xml AS [urlset!1!!xmltext]
          ,'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9' AS [urlset!1!xmlns]
          ,'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9' AS [urlset!1!xmlns:image]
    FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

---

**Template xml:**

```
<urlset xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc></loc>
    <changefreq></changefreq>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc></image:loc>
      <image:caption></image:caption>
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

What I want is a result like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>https://www.example.com/product/dkp-4658551/%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AA%D9%88-%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-27-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-%DA%AF%D9%84-%D9%88-%D9%BE%D9%86%D8%AC%D8%B1%D9%87-%DA%A9%D8%AF-v78-%D8%B1%D9%86%DA%AF-%D8%B7%D9%88%D8%B3%DB%8C</loc>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>https://example.com/mysite-products/3d1201f33f4e6dd6114ee6ec55be20fb5581f382_1615206830.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,m_lfit,h_350,w_350/quality,q_60</image:loc>
            <image:caption>مانتو زنانه 27 مدل گل و پنجره کد V78 رنگ طوسی</image:caption>
        </image:image>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: Not! I just want to generate an XML file @DaleK

Comment: I read the data from the product table @DaleK

Comment: ok. @DaleK
check my question

Comment: please check again @DaleK

Comment: It gives me the wrong output. No matter how hard I try, I can't get the output I want @DaleK

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Thank.u @DaleK  .

Comment: Nader, please see my previous comment. To help you, we need ##1-4 from you.

Comment: You code doesn't come even close to passing a syntax check. I just tried a quick `FOR XML PATH` against you base table and that returned half what you want without all the sub-queries. I suggest start simple and build it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because DDL and sample data population is not provided, I took a liberty to create it.

By using XQuery and its FLWOR expression, it is easy to create a sitemap XML.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    loc VARCHAR(2048), 
    changefreq VARCHAR(10),
    priority DECIMAL(2,1),
    image VARCHAR(2048),
    caption NVARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO @tbl (loc, changefreq, priority, image, caption) VALUES
('https://example.com/product1', 'hourly', 0.5, 'https://example.com/asset/img1.jpg', N'caption1'),
('https://example.com/product2', 'daily', 0.2, 'https://example.com/asset/img2.jpg', N'caption2');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'
    , 'http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1' AS [image])
SELECT (
    SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
{
    for $x in /root/r
    return <url>
        <loc>{data($x/loc)}</loc>
        <changefreq>{data($x/changefreq)}</changefreq>
        <priority>{data($x/priority)}</priority>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>{data($x/image)}</image:loc>
            <image:caption>{data($x/caption)}</image:caption>
        </image:image>
    </url>
}
</urlset>');
```

**Output**

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>https://example.com/product1</loc>
    <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://example.com/asset/img1.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:caption>caption1</image:caption>
    </image:image>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://example.com/product2</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.2</priority>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://example.com/asset/img2.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:caption>caption2</image:caption>
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: excellent. this is a best answer. @yitzhak-khabinsky tnx a lot 

Comment: @NaderGharibianFard, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Answer (score 3):

The following also returns what you require - seems a bit simpler to me. Also if you want to add the version and encoding I believe the only way you can do it is to convert to a string.

```
DECLARE @Xml XML = null, @XMLStr NVARCHAR(MAX) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'
    , 'http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1' AS image)  
SELECT @Xml = (SELECT loc, changefreq, [priority], [image] as [image:image/image:loc]
    , [caption] as [image:image/image:caption]
FROM (
  VALUES ('https://example.com/product1','https://example.com/asset/img1.jpg','title1', 10, 0.1)
      , ('https://example.com/product2','https://example.com/asset/img2.jpg','title1', 20, 0.2)
) P (loc, [image], caption, changefreq, [priority])
FOR XML PATH ('url'), ROOT('urlset'));

SELECT @Xml;

-- Convert to a string and add the `version` + `encoding` tag.
SELECT @XMLStr + CAST(@XML AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

Returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>https://example.com/product1</loc>
    <changefreq>10</changefreq>
    <priority>0.1</priority>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://example.com/asset/img1.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:caption>title1</image:caption>
    </image:image>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://example.com/product2</loc>
    <changefreq>20</changefreq>
    <priority>0.2</priority>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://example.com/asset/img2.jpg</image:loc>
      <image:caption>title1</image:caption>
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Note: You don't provide a mapping between your change frequency and the word which represents it.

Comment: @NaderGharibianFard note I have never done this before I did that just from reading the docs on `FOR XML PATH` - I'm sure you could have done the same :)

Comment: You helped me a lot to get my answer @Dale-K